# Powershell basics - incrementally increase a variable to manage a loop

Tags: powershell, for-loop, increment

I'm somewhat of a PowerShell beginner, and I'm struggling to get my code to break out of a For loop. More specifically, my `$parseCount` Variable is always being reset to "1" when calling `$ParseCount++`, even if some pre-existing conditions meant that its value was original "2".
Therefore, I keep getting stuck in an infinite loop.

In the below example, the script correctly deduces which level of "work" should be done, on the first pass. But then it'll always set the $ParseCount variable to 1, instead of to $ParseCount + 1.

I'm sure it's something easy. Thanks in advance for helping!

```
# all possible Scenarios

 If ($Scenario -ieq "Outcome1") {
                      $ParseCount=0
                      }

If ($Scenario -ieq "Outcome2") {
$ParseCount=1
}

If ($Scenario -ieq "Outcome3") {
                      $ParseCount=2
                      }

# Start the loop

For ($ParseCount -lt 3){

# determine what work to do

    If ($ParseCount=0){
             write-host "I'm doing some prerequisite stuff"
                }

    If ($ParseCount -gt 0){
             write-host "I'm doing all of the work, beacause prerequisite is done"
                           }

# Return to the top of the loop

write-host "ParseCount variable is:", $ParseCount
$ParseCount++
write-host "ParseCount was changed, is now set to:", $ParseCount

}
```

Sample output:

ParseCount variable is: 2
ParseCount was changed, is now set to 1

Comment: The line `If ($ParseCount=0)` is setting `$ParseCount` to 0. You need to change it to `If($ParseCount -eq 0)`. Also checkout [powershell comparision docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators?view=powershell-7)

Comment: Typically you'd use the `for` itself to perform the increment with `For ( ; $ParseCount -lt 3; $ParseCount++) { }`.  Also, you don't need to check on _every iteration_ if the prerequisites for the entire loop have been met, so you can simplify and optimize that to `If ($ParseCount -eq 0) { Write-Host "I'm doing some prerequisite stuff" } For ( ; $ParseCount -lt 3; $ParseCount++) { Write-Host "I'm doing all of the work, because prerequisite is done" }`.  See [Introducing the for-if anti-pattern](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20111227-00/?p=8793).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should change

```
    If ($ParseCount=0){
             write-host "I'm doing some prerequisite stuff"
                }

    If ($ParseCount -gt 0){
             write-host "I'm doing all of the work, beacause prerequisite is done"
                           }
```

(which would set `$ParseCount` back to 0)

into

```
    If ($ParseCount -eq 0){
             write-host "I'm doing some prerequisite stuff"
                }

    If ($ParseCount -gt 0){
             write-host "I'm doing all of the work, beacause prerequisite is done"
                           }
```